# C++ Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, expression, lvalue

writing this program for my c++ class and im running into an issue. My program reads the inputtted name and stores it into `name` it then wants to check for correct parameters under `_name`.. here are my class and its header file.

My error is specifically under `::setName` where i want to check or set my inputted name with _name for correct output under  `::display()`

PhoneNumber.cpp

```
using namespace oop244;


    void PhoneNumber::display() const{
        cout << "name: " << _name << ", Phone number: (" << _areacode << ") " << _localNumber / 10000 << "-" << _localNumber % 10000 << endl;
    }

    bool PhoneNumber::isValid() const
    {
        if (correctNum == false && correctArea == false){
            cout << _name << " does not have a valid phone number." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }
    void PhoneNumber::setName(const char name[])
    {
        cout << name << endl;

        _name = name;
    }
```

PhoneNumber.h

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 40
#define PHNO_MAX  999999
#define PHNO_MIN 100000
#define AREACODE_MIN 100
#define AREACODE_MAX  999
namespace oop244{

    class PhoneNumber{


    private:
        char _name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
        int _areacode;
        int _localNumber;
        bool _validPhoneNumber;
    public:

        void setName(const char name[]);
        void setPhoneNumber(int areaCode, int number);
        void display() const;
        bool isValid() const;


    };
};
```

Comment: Built-in arrays can't be assigned. Use `strncpy` or similar, or simply `std::string`.

Comment: Definitely use `std::string` intead of C-style strings if you can. I'd also recommend getting rid of `#define` constants in favor of `const` constants, e.g. `const auto MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 40;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign raw arrays. You need to copy the contents.

Assuming your class teacher forces you to use char arrays, you can for example use `strncpy` to copy the characters:

```
strncpy(_name, name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
```

You need to `#include <cstring>` for this.

If your class teacher allows it, better use `std::array<char,MAX_NAME_LENGTH>` or even `std::string`. Both can be copied by assigning.

Comment: in header file? or cpp?

Comment: Include at the top of your cpp (before or after other includes). `strncpy(...)` instead of the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

use standard string

```
#include <string>
```

and use

```
std::string _name;
```

in your class declarations instead of

```
char _name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
```

alternatively use c-style str-functions, as suggested in another answer

Comment: Basically, every `char[]` should be replaced with `std::string`. In the parameters too, as well as the members.

Comment: Some class teachers make restrictions on what types can be used. That's why you should also include a solution for the case `std::string` can *not* be used.

Comment: Agree, but OP said it's for a class, and most classes have specific restrictions on what to use (for example, you can not learn how to write a linked list if you are allowed to use `std::list` for that...)